# Getting user input, then sumbit to another site

Tags: php, textarea

I have a textarea input on my site where the user can input information, when they hit submit i'm trying to get my site to take that data and submit it to an external site. When the external site returns the results i want to get those results and return them back to my site.

What is the best way to go around this ?

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with [curl](http://Php.net/curl).

Other alternatives are,

- [fopen with URL wrappers](http://Php.net/fopen)
- [stream](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) functions
- [http](http://php.net/http) extension
- [fsockopen](http://Php.net/fsockopen)
- [sockets](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php) extension

Answer (score 0):

Take the input and submit it via [cURL](http://de.php.net/curl) to the site you want, set [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to 1 and you get the results as a return value of [curl_exec()](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php).

If the site you want to query uses POST, you want to have a look at CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. Otherwise you can append it to your (GET) Query-String using [http_build_query](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php).

Answer (score 0):

well you need to know the API the other site needs to receive the data in but I bet they will have a RESTful interface where you can use variables in the url.  Using php you can do something like:

```
  //get the text area value if it was part of a form which was posted
  $data = urlencode($_REQUEST['textareaname']);
  $othersiteresponse = file_get_contents('http://www.othersite.com/url.php?variable='.$data);
  //return this data
```